# Jenkins SCM polling - single schedule rule for all jobs

Tags: jenkins

All jobs defined in my Jenkins use SCM polling. I want to keep all of the schedule rules same and control it in a single place. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cool [Configuration slicing plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) to update the SCM Timer Trigger Slicer.

this will enable you to update multiple jobs at the same time.

Comment: It actually works. However, after changing the configuration using the plugin, `Git Polling Log` option is not available in a job view (what makes browsing really misleading). Any solutions? The option is back again after resaving the configuration, but it is inconvenient for multiple jobs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 'git polling log' option so i don't have a solution for that sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The nicest choice for things like that is JobDSL. You have the power of a real programming language.